# Determine if user dismissed push notification pop up (displaying multiple alert box at the same time)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

Right now when the app tries to register for push notification by calling `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications]`, there will be a pop up asking for user's permission. At the same time I have another alert box would like to prompt for user input upon first launch of the app (e.g. recommend them to perform purchase restore if they purchased anything previously).

Currently I am showing the alert after landing onto root view controller i.e. in `viewDidAppear`. However it happens that this alert will overlap with the pop up asking permission for push notification most of the time, which looks bad to me.

Is there anyway to get noticed after user has dismissed the pop up for push notification, or is there better way to handle the situation other than not register for push notification before my alert box was dismissed?

Thanks!

Comment: You know the notifications alert will displayed if the current permissions are undetermined.  You know it's dismissed when you get the appropriate callback/delegate call.  Act accordingly.

Comment: I checked about the callbacks like `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` and some other sources, it looks like that these callbacks (including the one for failed to register) will be invoked even if the user hasn't make any choice. Regarding current permission, seems there is no other way to get notified when it is changed besides checking it periodically?

Comment: why you are not registering for remote notifications after alert box prompt dismissed?

Comment: Because that would involve in many potential locations to make the call for registering push. For example, if I am going to do this after the user dismissed the alert box prompt them to perform purchase restore, I may need to make the call after user restored purchase successfully, cancelled the restoration, etc, which would likely result in overlapping with another box. At the same time the handling of these stuffs are in another common module, which I think it is kind of inappropriate to make this modification and add the register push call in it.

Answer (score 1):

When the native notifications prompt is presented, your app becomes inactive and the `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` fires. Your app will stay in the inactive state until the user responds "yes" or "no" to the push prompt.

Register for the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` so when that fires, you know the native push alert has been dismissed. Here is an example in Swift 3:

```
NSNotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, 
   selector: #selector(MyClass.showCustomModal), 
   name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, 
   object: nil)
```